# How to hide existing D3 chart and render new graph?

Tags: html, d3.js, svg, append, overlay

I've added a dropdown of checkbox options, when an option is selected it renders a D3 graph in the div `#chartContainer` and adds a new button tab for that chart above the container.

But if I select option two in the dropdown, the second tab button is added but the second graph is rendered below the first graph rendered.

My intention is to hide the current rendered svg and show the next graph when a new graph option is selected.

How to hide existing D3 chart and render new graph?

*chartContainer and chart options checkbox:*

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="chartDropdown" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabindex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Chart 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabindex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Chart 2</a></li>                                   
</ul>


    <div class="row top-buffer" id="tabContainer">

            <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="chartTabs">
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#fragment-1">Chart</a></li>
            </ul>


            @* render chart in this container *@
            <div id="chartContainer">


            </div>
        </div>
```

Toggle chart visibility by id method:

```
   function toggle_chart_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'block')
            e.style.display = 'none';
        else
            e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

*Snippet of script that creates tab and draws graph in ChartContainer:*

```
         /* dataSet object requriement: data, categories, filter lists*/
        function visualize(rawDataSet) {
            //0. process data
            let dataSet = process(rawDataSet, 'month');
            let mode = 'month';
            // let dataSet = process(rawDataSet, 'day');
            //1. draw legend and all radio button fitlers
            //2. draw main chart

            let newStackChart = stackChart().data(dataSet).tickFormat("%b/%y");

            //Dynamically create a new tab for the rendered graph
            var ul = tabs.find( "ul" );
            $( '<li><a href="#fragment-' + ++tabCounter + '">Chart</a></li>' ).appendTo( ul );
            tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
            tabs.tabs('select', tabCounter - 1);


            //toggle the previous chart to hide
            //to make room for the next chart render
            //not sure how to get the id of the current svg rendered
            toggle_chart_visibility(svg);

            d3.select('div#chartContainer')
                .append("div")
                .classed("svg-container", true) //container class to make it responsive
                .append("svg")
                //responsive SVG needs these 2 attributes and no width and height attr
                .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
                .attr("viewBox", "0 0 2000 2000")
                //class to make it responsive
                .classed("svg-content-responsive", true)
                .call(newStackChart);

        }
```

Comment: I haven't tested yet, but will doing that delete my first or previous rendered graph? I'm aiming to create a new container and button over the original so I can tab between graphs. Presently instead it renders the graph appended below the original.

Comment: You only want to draw both graphs once, then hide/show the one selected?

Comment: Yes so if I select option one in list, a graph and tab button are drawn.        If I select option two a second graph is drawn in a new container on overlayed on top of the first graph container. Clicking tab1 will tab back to the first graph rendered, clicking tab2 will tab to the second graph. All within the same area on the screen.

Comment: Ok then what you can do is : when I click on tab 1, set the style of graph 2 to `display : none` and style of graph 1 to `display : block` and vice versa

Comment: Ok makes sense, but at the moment when I already have a graph rendered then select option 2 it draws a second graph below the first instead of overlayed on top of the first.

Comment: When you select option 2, then the 1st graph will be hidden (display : none) so it will overlayed on top of the first

Comment: So I need to hide the current graph svg in the container on the option click event? Any idea how I can get a handle on the current svg graph id that is displaying? Currently I thin the svg id needs to be created dynamically based on the button clicked..with a counter of some sort.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118565/discussion-between-tim-b-and-brian-j).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is draw all graph in different `div` with unique `id`

```
d3.select("#chartContainer")
    .selectAll("div")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('div')
  .attr('id', function(d, i){ return 'id' + i })
  .text(function(d){ return 'This is chart ' + d;}) // add your graph here
```

Then add an event on the tabs that will hide all graph `div` except the one selected like that :

```
d3.select("ul#tabs")
    .selectAll("li")
    .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('li')
  .text(function(d){ return d; })
  .on('click', function(d, i){onlyShowByID('id' + i); });
```

with `onlyShowByID` doing

```
function onlyShowByID(id) {
   d3.select("#chartContainer")
    .selectAll("div")
    .style('display', function(d){ 
      var currentID = d3.select(this).attr('id');
        return currentID === id ? 'block' : 'none'
      })
}
```

See this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/m4mqrnxk/1/

Comment: I tried a variation of this code using a dropdown of checkboxes to create the each graph type which works. But the tabs that are created for each graph rendered don't change the graph displayed. It's as if the click event isn't firing for the tabs - Any ideas?  http://hastebin.com/kihiyaxave.xml